# Join two subquerys

Tags: join, subquery

I would like to see how many times someone has scored more than two goals (first subquery) and how many goals in total the same person scored (second subquery).
But I don't know how to 'join' both subquery in a proper way.

```
SELECT  o2.aantal,o3.gesc,
            p.persid,p.voornaam,p.tussenvoegsel,p.achternaam
            FROM 
            ( SELECT o.persid, count(o.gesc) AS aantal
               FROM opstelere o where o.gesc>2
               GROUP BY o.persid ) AS o2,               
            
             (select o.persid,sum(o.gesc) as gesc from opstelere o )  as o3              
             
             JOIN personen AS p  ON p.persid = o3.persid                      
             
             ORDER BY aantal desc,gesc asc,achternaam asc
```

Comment: Sample data and the output you'd like to obtain from that data would help greatly, as would a tag for the specific DBMS you're using. Please [edit] your question and take care of those issues.

Comment: Please add the tag to your question of the db you're using

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple `group by`:

```
SELECT
  aantal,
  gesc,
  persid,
  voornaam,
  tussenvoegsel,
  achternaam,
  count(o.gesc) AS aantal
FROM opstelere o
GROUP BY
  aantal,
  gesc,
  persid,
  voornaam,
  tussenvoegsel,
  achternaam
HAVING count(o.gesc) > 2
ORDER BY aantal desc, gesc, achternaam
```